# Python MySQL query using string comparison in where clause

Tags: python, mysql

I have a strange issue where I can't get an SQL query with parameter to work with a string comparison in the where clause - I don't get a row back. when i connect to the MySQL db via bash, the query works.

- python 3.7.3
- mysql-connector-python==8.0.11
- mysql 5.7

works (getting my row):

```
select * from my_table where my_column = 'my_string';
```

also works (getting my row):

```
cursor.execute(
    """
        select *
        from my_table
        where my_column = 'my_string'
    """
)
```

doesn't work (`cursor.fetchall()` is `[]`):

```
cursor.execute(
    """
        select *
        from my_table
        where my_column = '%s'
    """,
    ('my_string')
)
```

Comment: `Doesn't work`  means what exactly? Do you get an error?

Comment: there was a comment that's now removed - writing ('my_string',) with a comma after the string. please add as answer so i can promote it as correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with tuples. I think you need `('my_string',)`.

FYI I wrote the original comment mentioned by @tscherg in his comment below the question.

Comment: this along with removing the quotes around %s did it!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes:

```
cursor.execute(
    """
        select *
        from my_table
        where my_column = %s
    """,
    ('my_string')
)
```

Comment: that's not it. getting a MySQL Error (42000) telling me to check the syntax near %s